# Jquery performance on android

Tags: android, jquery

Just finalizing a project for a client, will remove link once answered.

http://da.cronus.fweb.com.au/

On iOS and desktop the animations/scrolling are very smooth.  As soon as it hits android things get very laggy (tested on nexus 7, Galaxy S4 and galaxy tab 3)

Anything i can do to speed things up?

Comment: I don't know if this will help you but on my Nexus 4 it's really bad in Chrome and Opera but very smooth in FireFox. I believe Opera switched to webkit.

Comment: Also, in Chrome on my linux pc, if I decrease the window size to a phone or tablet resolution, the content adjusts but only the first slider works past the first slide.

Comment: It could be the device video card is not that good for your animation requirements  ?

Comment: It works perfectly on an iPad 1, but on my Galaxy Tab 3 / Galaxy S4 it runs like pap, i highly doubt its the specs.  It seems something Android based

Comment: shrink the file sizes and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

first of all some images are pretty heavy for mobile devices

it should not affect the animations but still ...

codewise the only part that seems slow to me is

```
$('.column p').each(function(){         
  if($(this).html().length < 1){ $(this).remove() }         
})
```

in custom.js line 665

**so i guess if the animations are slow it must be a device / spec issue**

but there is probably something to change with those line of code that could help your javascript.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the only plugin i found that does what i want for turning the text into columns also leaves a few empty <p> tags lying around.  That code only executes on window resize/first load though so shouldn't affect the pages performance after loading

Comment: you are right i did not notice it was on resize / first load only and you are also right it should not affect the animations however if u want to improve your code overall i think you should try $(".column p:empty").remove() tester on jsperf : http://jsperf.com/length-vs-empty

Comment: by the way the website animations work great on my Galaxy nexus ;)

Answer (score 0):

For Sliding you can use Flexslider plugin. Plugin supports touch and it is responsive. I think some problem with sliding plugin only.

Answer (score 0):

Switch from java script animations to CSS3 animations - they are hardware accelerated on most Android 2.3+ devices.

Comment: Not an option as it must be IE8+ Compatable

Comment: http://playground.benbarnett.net/jquery-animate-enhanced/

You could try out this jquery plugin. It is suppose to use CSS3 transforms when possible.

Comment: You can easily detect you are on a mobile device http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ - if you are not fallback to Java Script animations

Answer (score 0):

jQuery itself is OK on Android. I use it all the time.  This could be a poorly coded slider plugin. However, you have some large images around 2mb and I think this could be optimized.  I would do this first. You can also move the js files to the bottom and also compress and merge them.  These are all optimization techniques that need to be done first and are not a waste of time.  I'd also use responsive CSS on the images to display different sizes for device resolutions.  Bootstrap has some solutions for the images sizes.  After your page is optimized for mobile then you can re-evaluate if the slider is still slow or it was just large images.

Comment: I had replaced the images with much smaller files which showed a tiny increase, but not much.  Its not just the slider, its the sections you scroll sideways also (underneath that) are quite jerky. Just to add it's all hand coded, the only plugin is the one to detect touch.

Comment: I would break up the features into separate tests and load each test in Android individually. Right now you have so much going on with the page it is difficult to pin the issue down.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on my Galaxy Note II and it works quite smooth. If you are trying to improve it in anyway, i would recommend [swipejs.com](http://swipejs.com) for mobile and [flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) for the desktop version (although flexslider is completely working on mobile too, i just found swipe.js to be easier to setup)

Good luck and have fun! :D

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very generic.So i would say, you need to minimize background processing  as for as possible in scrolling(if doing some processing for scrolled data) or in animation or in any other activities.

As mobile devices have less resources.

Answer (score 0):

Animation performance on android is not something you can just bolt-on with an IE jQuery plugin 'that makes it work in IE8' and expect it to work similar on android.

Remember that Android runs on a *wide* variety of devices, all with their own performance issues and some with even crappier versions of the android webkit variant than others. Expect huge differences between last-generation quad-core tablets/phones and low-budget devices.

My advice:

- try a jquery plugin that automatically uses css3 animations instead of jquery looped where available (but no guarantees there)
- try a jquery plugin that optimizes the jquery animations with the use of requestAnimationFrame (
  http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/ )
- As others have mentioned: You can't just throw 2mb images to a phone and expect them to animate smoothly. Optimize assets for the device you're serving them to (e.g. a max 800x600 pic for a phone)
- If all that fails: Optimize manually, by enabling android browser debug settings and adding -webkit-transform 3d-transitions to the elements that need to animate so that the layer is rendered by the GPU.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned performance on android, but the first time that I loaded the site on Firefox it was pretty slow as well. After looking at your slide images, I found that the slide are way too big (~2mb), as other people have mentioned. 
PNGs aren't the best choice unless you must have transparency, as they are bigger than JPEGs right off the bat. I would take the images and optimize them for the web using Ps. If you really wanted to be super-efficient, you could have another set of smaller images intended for android. Hope this helps you out. Happy programming!
Grey

Comment: I do appreciate that the images need changing, I threw them in at the clients request. However before those i was using a much smaller sized image and was having the exat same issue, it affected performance but only marginally.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd use css transitions. I've found that they work much better on mobile especially Android. I realize that in a desktop environment you'd have much broader support using a javascript transition but mobile is a different story.

You could hybridize....

http://jsfiddle.net/PHPVT/

```
$("#target").on("click", function () {
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
})
```

use javascript events to fire css transitions :)

I use it all the time when I have to build for ie8 since it doesn't fire :hover states on anything other than anchor tags.

Comment: But surely on non CSS3 browsers, you won't get the animation and just the end point? What about on the sliding sections below, it would just be updating the CSS matrix just as often as it changes the scroll value.

Comment: @ Mat Taylor That is correct. They will not see the transition but things will simply change from state A to B on an older browser. If you are updating a css value based on scroll you will get a smooth(ER) transition even on those old browsers... but... Most mobile devices use layer composting to make inertial scrolling smoother. What this means is that when you start scrolling on a mobile your site will go totally static until it stops scrolling. After it stops the site will come back to life and update.

Comment: That is only true on the iPhone, and most of that front page the scrolling is done by jQuery, which doesn't pause animations.  The client wants the animations working on IE rather than just snapping to the end of the animation.  It currently doesn't work on IE8 due to a couple of errors that need amending, but earlier testing showed it ran fine. It's purely on Android that is having issues as far as i can tell.

Comment: Sorry just to add, the client is way over on their time due to lots of changes, so i really don't want to have to do any major re-coding if possible

Comment: There is an animation lib called greensock and it out performs jQuery's animate 8 days a week. The reality is that jQuery is incredibly inefficient. If JQ is handling your scroll than it's likely chewing up cycles like Cookie Monster which would explain your performance problems. Sounds like you need to switch animation libraries since css3 transitions are not an option and jQ animate is simply not efficient enough for most older / mobile browsers.